# Sort using condition in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Not sure how to approach this problem. Would greatly appreciate if some one can tell me if this is doable and if yes , how.

I have a collection in Mongo and every document in that collection has a field called Rank. When the user clicks a button, I have access to the req.user( with some custom fields) because I am using passport for authentication(both OAUTH and local).

Here is what I am looking for.

On the next page after the button click, I want to display 20 individuals who are ranked above the req.user rank. So assume I am the req.user and my rank is 24, I want all records having rank from 4 to 23 sorted from 4 to 23. Is this doable? Please guide.

This is how a single document in my collection looks like and the Rank field is somewhere in the middle

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed3c6c2776524724f2fae63"),
    "Player_Name" : "Abhimanyu Sen",
    "Player_ID" : "P0001",
    "Player_ActivePlayer" : "N",
    "Edition_1_Rank" : "0",
    "Edition_2_Rank" : "0",
    "Edition_3_Rank" : "67",
    "Edition_4_Rank" : "113",
    "Edition_5_Rank" : "185",
    "Player_Owner" : "N",
    "Edition5_TeamOwner" : "N",
    "Edition6_TeamOwner" : "N",
    "Edition1_Performance" : "Did Not Play",
    "Edition2_Performance" : "Did Not Play",
    "Edition3_Performance" : "Round of 32 - Challengers Cup",
    "Edition4_Performance" : "Did Not Play",
    "Edition5_Performance" : "Did Not Play",
    "Total_Tournament_Matches_Played" : 8,
    "Total_Tournament_Matches_Won" : 0,
    "Total_Tournament_Matches_Lost" : 8,
    "Total_Tournament_Matches_Points" : 3.0,
    "Total_Challenge_Matches_Played" : 0,
    "Total_Challenge_Matches_Won" : 0,
    "Total_Challenge_Matches_Lost" : 0,
    "Total_Challenge_Matches_Points" : 0.0,
    "Total_Matches_Played" : 8,
    "Total_Matches_Won" : 0,
    "Total_Matches_Lost" : 8,
    "Total_Points" : 3.0,
    "Total_Games_Won" : 0,
    "Winning_Percentage" : 0.0,
    "Player_FDR" : 0.0,
    "Rank" : 185,
    "Player_ELORating" : "",
    "Player_IsHeavyTraveller" : "",
    "Player_NickName" : "",
    "Player_ImageURL" : "",
    "Player_CompanyName" : "",
    "Player_Designation" : "",
    "Player_DateOfBirth" : "",
    "Player_TelephoneNumber" : "",
    "Player_Website" : "",
    "Player_LinkedinProfile" : "",
    "Player_FBLink" : "",
    "Player_InstagramLink" : "",
    "Player_TwitterLink" : "",
    "Player_Interests" : "",
    "Player_Blog" : "",
    "Player_Posts" : "",
    "Player_Messages" : "",
    "Total_Games_Lost" : 24,
    "Total_Weighted_Points" : 2.65
}
```

Comment: please provide sample data json.

Comment: ana i posted above, but the formatting gets all skewed not sure what the issue is

Comment: Have you tried (sort:1) and then adding skip, limit to same query? Your question is somewhat ambiguous, is the first result showed to user not paginated (before clicking next)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do as this:

```
 db.getCollection('your-collection').aggregate([
        {$match:{
            Rank: {$gt:24}
            }},
         {$sort:{Rank:1}},
         { $limit: 20
             }
        ])
```

Put the user's rank instead of 24

Comment: ah got it that simple..sorry ana new to Mongo and wasting a lot of time navigating docs,,just easier asking a question..thanks once again you are the best

Comment: It's alright. I forgot the sort part. gonna fix it right now